# AngularJs : How to call child component method from parent components

Tags: angularjs

I am doing Migration of AngularJS application to Angular 4.Currently preparing for migration that is conversion to Component based architechture.

> My question is how can I call child component method from parent component.

I know in Angular 4 we can use @ViewChild to access the child method. Is there any equivalent for angularjs 1.6 or any other approach that can help in smoother migration.

Comment: In Angular2+ event streams a passed to components using RxJS observable objects. To add rxJS to AngularJS see [Returning data from AngularJS service to controller with RxJS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47917736/5535245).

Comment: Thanks for response. I am already using RxJs but I wanted to understance if anything like @ViewChild is available in Angularjs

Answer (score 3):

In angularJS we use `$broadcast` event to communicate with parent controller to child controller. But this is a `$scope` method. Since angular 2 drops the scope, you cannot use this event.

The best solution is already mentioned in the question. `ViewChild` allows much more control to the user compare to the broadcasts. So my recommendation is to go with `ViewChild`

Answer (score 1):

Since Angular2+ event streams are passed to components using RxJS observable objects, to make the migration to Angular 2+ smoother, use RxJS observables in AngularJS as well.

To add [rxJS to AngularJS](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/rx.angular.js) components:

```
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/rx/dist/rx.all.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/rx-angular/dist/rx.angular.js"></script>
```

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['rx']);

app.controller("parentCtrl", function($scope, rx) {
    $scope.subject = new rx.Subject(); 

    $scope.onEvent = function(message) {         
        $scope.subject.onNext(message); 
    };

});
```

```
app.component("childComponent", {
    controller: "childCtrl",
    bindings: { subject: "<" },
    template: `<div>{{$ctrl.message}}</div>`
});

app.controller("childCtrl", function(rx) {
    var subscription;
    this.$onChanges = function(changes) {
        if (changes.subject} {
            subscription = subject.subscribe(function onNext(message) {
                console.log(message);
                $ctrl.message = message;
            });
        };
    }; 

    this.$onDestroy = function() {
        if (subscription) {
            subscription.dispose();
        };
    };
});
```